# KindError: No model class found for kind. When is the ndb.Model._kind_map actually updated?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on refactoring our models module by splitting it up from one big file into multiple files. It was difficult trying to get around the inevitable dependency loops introduced by the single file, but we managed.

Now, to our surprise, when testing the new code base on a testing instance, we're getting `KindError: No model class found for kind 'Foo'. Did you forget to import it?` errors.

Since our unit tests were all green, we thought it must be due to existing entries storing 'old' references to the model classes.

It took some time to narrow down the issue to the [`_kind_map`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#2792) property of ndb.Model. I'm confused as to when exactly this map is updated internally? When/How does AppEngine decide to add a model class to this map?

We're trying a workaround by calling the [`_fix_up_properties()`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#3205) method explicitly for each model in a temporary handler, but I'm not sure if that is advisable and if there aren't any unintended side-effects down the line.

**EDIT:**

I tried printing out `_kind_map.keys()` on 2 different versions of the app. One is the old, non-refactored version, and the other is the refactored version.

On the old version, all models are listed as keys (39 models). On the refactored version, it only lists 5 models. These 5 models are the only ones imported on the handler used to print out the keys. So I guess the map is updated every time a model is imported? But why did the non-refactored version print out 39? The handler to print also only imports 5 models there.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you get the error? Where in your code are you trying to reference `Foo`?

Comment: Happens when retrieving an existing entity of `Foo`.

Comment: Does `Foo` have any `ndb.KeyProperty` fields that reference an entity in another module using a string instead of an imported model name? For example `ndb.KeyProperty('Bar')` instead of `ndb.KeyProperty(Bar)` where `Bar` is an imported model.

Comment: Yes. In fact, `Foo` is a `KeyProperty` of another, and the error happens during `some_object.foo.get()`.

Comment: Then I would expect that to be the error. In the model class for `some_object`, you could try changing `foo = ndb.KeyProperty('Foo')` to `foo = ndb.KeyProperty(Foo)` (and remember to `import Foo` above your model).

Comment: Oh, we're trying to avoid that due to the dependency loops it might introduce. But yes, my edit seems to agree that importing a model updates the `_kind_map`. Hmm need more thought in this.

Comment: As you have found out, the `_kind_map` is updated on import. I have seen a few errors where people don't import a particular model and perform a GQL query and get the same error, or when they break DRY rules and define the Model in a couple of different files and don't import consistently.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Makes sense now. How do I close this? Or could one of you answer?

Answer (score 4):

Guido van Rossum [posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/Rl2v4lirbsU) in 2012

> Most likely the module containing the class definition for Account is
>   not imported (directly or indirectly) by the code that executes the
>   get() request. Adding the import should make the issue go away. (This
>   is because **the kind map is updated when the model class definition is
>   read**. Given only the kind name, e.g. 'Account', NDB doesn''t know
>   which module to import to find the model class.

If you import your model from another module, such as models.MyKind, then NDB does not recognise 'MyKind' as a kind only 'models.MyKind'.

Following generates a KindError,

```
import models
import ndb
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=encoded_key)
entity = key.get() #KindError
```

Move last two lines to models.py, such as a @staticmethod and it works. 
There may be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to import the specific model into the refactored module:

```
from models import Foo
```

This updates the `_kind_map` for the code in that module.